# why www. prefix is required(must) with my domain hosted on AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, web-hosting, nameservers

I have a domain *xxxxx.co.in*(brought it through goddady) hosted on **AWS S3** as a **static web host**. Which is only working good when accessing as [www.xxxxx.co.in](http://www.xxxxx.co.in) but It is not working with [xxxxx.co.in](http://xxxxx.co.in) .

I have brought it through goddady.

Comment: You can redirect from  xxxxx.co.in to www. xxxxx.co.in

Comment: Thanks, I got the soln.

Comment: Just aaded another CNAME and redirected it to the same.

Comment: Here is the official docs on this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add cname record with @ and www

and redirect your url xxxx.co.in